# Swift - UICollisionBehavior delegate methods not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollisionbehavior

I'm doing a simple animation which requires me to handle some collisions with boundaries.

I have a class, viewcontroller, which I extend to be a UICollisionBehaviorDelegate so I can recognize and handle view collisions.

For some reason, when a collision happens, my delegate methods never fire.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var fallingImageViews: [UIImageView]!
    var downAnimator: UIDynamicAnimator!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //imagine fallingImageViews Initializers happening here

        downAnimator = initializeAnimators()
    }

    func initializeAnimators() -> UIDynamicAnimator {
        let downwardAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)

        downwardAnimator.addBehavior(setBoundaries())
        downwardAnimator.addBehavior(setGravity())
        downwardAnimator.addBehavior(setBounciness())
        downwardAnimator.delegate = self

        return downwardAnimator
    }

    func setBoundaries() -> UICollisionBehavior {
        let boundaries = UICollisionBehavior(items: fallingImageViews)
        boundaries.collisionDelegate = self

        // prevent collisions between items
        boundaries.collisionMode = .boundaries

        boundaries.setTranslatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

        return boundaries
    }
}

// MARK: Collision Behavior Delegate
extension ViewController: UICollisionBehaviorDelegate, UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate {

    func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, endedContactFor item: UIDynamicItem, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?) {
        print(identifier)
    }
    func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactFor item: UIDynamicItem, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?, at p: CGPoint) {
        print(identifier)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I completely scrapped my old answer and updated it. I'm sorry I mislead you, but here is my revised answer:*

The idea is that you add behaviors to the objects you want animated (in your case, your `fallingImageViews`).

So all the code here should actually go into a class that inherits from UIImageView (in my example code you'll see that I'm inheriting from a CardCtrl object, but it might as well be a UIImageView).

The only changes you have to make is your `UIDynamicAnimator`'s reference view has to be `superview` and that all the the reference views for all your animation behaviors are set to `[self]`.

Here is some example code from one of my old projects:

```
@IBDesignable class SlidingCard: CardCtrl, UICollisionBehaviorDelegate
{
   ...
    //MARK: - Private Properties

    private var gripHeightAnch: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    private var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
    private var dynamicItem: UIDynamicItemBehavior!
    private var collisionBnds: UICollisionBehavior!
    private var snap: UISnapBehavior!
    private var botBndryPt: CGFloat!
    private var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!
    private var pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    ...

    //MARK: - Delegate Methods

    func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactFor item: UIDynamicItem,
                           withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?, at p: CGPoint)
    {
        guard let identifier = identifier else {return}
        if String(describing: identifier) == "bot"
        {
            sendActions(for: .touchDragOutside)
        }
        else
        {
            sendActions(for: .touchDragInside)
        }
    }

    ...

    //MARK: - Private Setup Methods

    private func defineSlideBehavior()
    {
        if animator == nil
        {
            animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: superview!)
        }
        animator!.removeAllBehaviors()

        //Check to see if behaviors are already installed because .removeAllBehaviors() doesn't
        //always work
        var addItem = true
        var addBounds = true
        var addGravity = true
        for blarHar in animator!.behaviors
        {
            if blarHar.isKind(of: UIDynamicItem.self)
            {
                addItem = false
            }
            if blarHar.isKind(of: UICollisionBehavior.self)
            {
                addBounds = false
            }
            if blarHar.isKind(of: UIGravityBehavior.self)
            {
                addGravity = false
            }
        }
        //Make it so the card doesn't wobble
        if dynamicItem == nil && addItem
        {
            dynamicItem = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [self])
            dynamicItem.allowsRotation = false
            dynamicItem.elasticity = 0
        }
        animator!.addBehavior(dynamicItem)

        //Add two boundaries for the drawer to collide with
        if collisionBnds == nil && addBounds
        {
            collisionBnds = UICollisionBehavior(items: [self])
            collisionBnds.collisionDelegate = self
        }
        botBndryPt = frame.maxY * 2 + 1.5
        collisionBnds.removeAllBoundaries()
        collisionBnds.addBoundary(withIdentifier: "top" as NSCopying,
                                  from: CGPoint(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY - 1.5),
                                  to: CGPoint(x: frame.maxX, y: frame.minY - 1.5))
        collisionBnds.addBoundary(withIdentifier: "bot" as NSCopying,
                                  from: CGPoint(x: frame.minX, y: botBndryPt),
                                  to: CGPoint(x: frame.maxX, y: botBndryPt))
        animator!.addBehavior(collisionBnds)

        //Define the initial gravity that affects the drawer
        if addGravity
        {
            gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [self])
            gravity.gravityDirection = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -gravityStrength)
            animator!.addBehavior(gravity)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now, the boundaries are being applied correctly - ie, the elements in  fallingimageViews collide with the reference bounds.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that when this collision happens, the `collisionBehaviorBeganContactFor method` isn't fired.

Comment: Your delegate isn't firing because your view controller is conforming to the UICollisionBehaviorDelegate, not your fallingImageViews.
If you assign the collisionDelegate to self, then your view controller becomes the observer for the collision, but in your case, your view controller owns no collision boundaries, so how is it supposed to detect collisions? (sorry I accidentally pressed enter too early before I could fully type out my answer)

Comment: Did you try out my suggestion? (changing `items: fallingImageViews` to `items: [self.view]`)

Comment: lol I did the same thing with my first reply.

ok, so I need to extend my fallingImageViews, (which is `[UIImageView]`) to conform to the UICollisionBehaviorDelegate?

Comment: Yes I tried that, it made the view starting floating up for some reason

Comment: Your example code doesn't include your `setGravity()` func. I'm assuming the same problem is in that function as well. (otherwise, just reverse the direction of the gravity)

Comment: You know, I was looking back at some code I did (almost exactly the same as what you're doing here) and I admit some of my advise is no good.

You're right, your fallingImageViews have to conform to the UICollisionBehaviorDelegate, but your UIDynamicAnimator's reference view has to be superview. Let me edit my response.

Comment: I completely revised my response above. I'm sorry I gave you bad advise in these comments, but my new response is correct. 


I really struggled with this stuff before as well, and it took me forever to arrive at the excerpt I gave you above (It's a view that acts like a drawer and closes/opens itself when dragged beyond a certain point). 

Note that I have the gravity direction reversed because I want my view to float to the top, so just get rid of that negative sign.

If you need more clarification, just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the revision Xavier, I moved all the logic into a new class, so that each imageView has it's own animator and behaviors. Unfortunately, the delegate method in the new class still doesn't fire :(

Comment: I don't have enough rep to go into chat, so let me know if email is more convenient.